# How to launch (run) specific shell script using double click ubuntu

Tags: matlab

I have installed MATLAB on my ubuntu and I can launch (run) it from terminal.
the problem is that I cannot run it using double click as it fails to launch.
Any help?
[image: directory and permission]

[image: file and permission]

Comment: What does it say in the tab 'open with'?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Oh, you're right. I mis-read that screenshot, my bad. Deleting comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't need to do that. If you want to launch MATLAB from the Unity menu, you don't have to change those permissions and probably shouldn't.

All you have to do is run `sudo apt-get install matlab-support` in Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). That should make it so you can access MATLAB via the Unity launcher. You may have to log out and back in again to make all of changes take affect.

Then, if you don't want to have to run MATLAB as root each time, you'll want to run `cd ~ && sudo chown YOURUSERNAME -R ~/.matlab/`.

However, you only want to launch it by going into that folder and double-clicking on the executable, run these commands:

```
sudo chmod +rwx /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/matlab
sudo chown YOURUSERNAME -R /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/
```

Comment: @Bondoque No problem, glad I could help :)